# Call Subroutine from backgroundworker

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I have a project that I am attempting to setup multiple backgroundworkers in.

[Old Code]
-backgroundworker1 as an object on the form

```
sub run()
   'backgroundworker1.runworkerasync()
end sub

sub do-work
    'Run process calling sub "CopyDirectory"
end sub
```

-This all worked fine.

I have changed the backgroundworker to the following code

```
Dim NewWorker As New BackgroundWorker
                NewWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
                NewWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
                AddHandler NewWorker.DoWork, AddressOf BackgroundWorker1_DoWork
                AddHandler NewWorker.ProgressChanged, AddressOf_ BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged ' Old worker sub but still works
                AddHandler NewWorker.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf_ BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted' Old worker sub but still works
                If NewWorker.IsBusy <> True Then
                    NewWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
                End If
```

When I "Do Work"

```
Private Sub Work2(ByVal CompNumber As Integer, ByVal Destination As String, ByVal Worker As BackgroundWorker)
    ' I can see the step happen to here
    CopyDirectory(Source, Destination, "Computer " + CompNumber, Worker)
    ' I never can stepthrough to here
    AppendTextBox(rtbStatusLog, Now() + " ?" + " Completed?" + vbCrLf)
End Sub
```

I can step through the code and see the point of my comment, but once i step and the "copydirectory" sub is to be called, stepping ends and it acts like "worker complete"

```
 Private Sub CopyDirectory(ByVal sourcePath As String, ByVal destinationPath As String, ByVal TargetName As String, ByVal Worker As BackgroundWorker)
      Dim SourceDirectoryInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(sourcePath)
        ' If the destination folder don't exist then create it
        If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(destinationPath) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath)
        End If

        Dim fileSystemInfo As System.IO.FileSystemInfo
        For Each fileSystemInfo In SourceDirectoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos
            Dim destinationFileName As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationPath, fileSystemInfo.Name)

            ' Now check whether its a file or a folder and take action accordingly
            If TypeOf fileSystemInfo Is System.IO.FileInfo Then
                System.IO.File.Copy(fileSystemInfo.FullName, destinationFileName, True)
                Worker.ReportProgress(0)
                AppendTextBox(rtbStatusLog, Now() + " ?" + TargetName + ":? " + "File Copied: " + destinationFileName + vbCrLf)

            Else
                ' Recursively call the mothod to copy all the neste folders
                CopyDirectory(fileSystemInfo.FullName, destinationFileName, TargetName, Worker)
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

I have attempted to put a break in the copydirectory sub but it is never hit.

I feel this has something to do with threading and how I have created the backgroundworker but I am unsure my mistake.

Comment: We need to know what `'Stuff` is in the CopyDirectory.  You can't access controls in there since you are in a background thread.  Are you getting an error?  It would help if you shared it with us.

Comment: I added in the 'Stuff. I do not get an error. The process acts like "work complete" and just ends the do_work.

Comment: Does AppendTextBox append to a TextBox?  That would be a control.  You would have to invoke that method to get it to the UI thread.

Comment: Any exception will abort the code.  It is reported back in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler with the `e.Error` property.  Forgetting to check this is a standard bug.

Comment: Color me stupid. I captured the error and I was being an idiot. This isn't related to my backgroundworkers at all. When I called "copydirectory" I sent through computernumber and treated it like a string when it's an integer. Added .tostring and fixed my issue.

Comment: I can't figure out the hochpoch in this code. How does your code even compile with `AddressOf_` ?. And why do you need a recursive method after all? You can get the entire file list in the folder and its sub-folders easily with `IO.Directory.GetFiles(xx, "*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)`, and then loop over the list and copy files.